# Is there a function that shows if the numbers are decreasing or increasing in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe of flights, and was wondering if there is a function that shows if the number of flights for an airline company is increasing or decreasing?

The dataframe is the 2001 one you can download it from here: http://stat-computing.org/dataexpo/2009/the-data.html

I expect the output to show the name of the UniqueCarrier code and if the ouccarance is increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Include an example dataset so we can visually see what you mean. Make sure this dataset is copy-able by us, not a picture. Ideally you want to add an expected output based on your example dataset.

Comment: it can decrease between first and second row and increase between second and third row. So is it decreasing or increasing ?

Comment: `df.diff()` Maybe?

Comment: Thanks, Scott I will try it!

Comment: Furas, for example, I want to see if the ouccarance of the UniqueCarrier code has increased.

Answer (score 2):

Use -

```
print(df['1'].is_monotonic) #non-strict (will be True in case of duplicates)
print(df['1'].is_monotonic and df['1'].is_unique) #strict (will be False in case of duplicates)
```